# Pour count for mL?

Tags: cocktails, pouring

**This question relates to free-pouring liquor using a pour spout when making cocktails and mixing liqours.** I hope this question is acceptable in this Stack Exchange.

So I wanted to have a pour count for mL (where I live we use metric). However, I also want a count for imperial units since some recipes use imperial units. My idea is to use a number count for imperial (since this is already a thing) and a syllable count for metric.

The imperial unit count:

| Count: | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Volume [Oz]: | 1/4 | 1/2 | 3/4 | 1 |

My idea was to use 6 syllables for metric (so I could at least do 30mL with one "count" before restarting), where each syllable is 5mL. Any ideas to what syllables I might use to count? I tried "Ba-Ba-Ba-Ba-Car-Di" (modified the word Bacardi). The upside is that 4 of the syllables are the same, so they take the same amount of time to pronounce (hence a consistent volume of liquor). The downside is that it is hard to say "correctly" in your head because there are four Ba's in a row.

| Count: | Ba | Ba | Ba | Ba | Car | Di |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Volume [mL]: | 5 | 10 | 15 | 20 | 25 | 30 |

Another suggestion might be "do-re-mi-fa-so-la-ti-do":

| Count: | Do | Re | Mi | Fa | So | La | Ti | Do |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Volume [mL]: | 5 | 10 | 15 | 20 | 25 | 30 | 35 | 40 |

If I want volumes greater than those in the count, I would just re-start the count. For example, if I want 45mL I do:

"Ba-Ba-Ba-Ba-Car-Di-Ba-Ba-Ba" or "Do-Re-Mi-Fa-So-La-Ti-Do-Do".

15 mL would be "Ba-Ba-Ba" or "Do-Re-Mi", a barspoon (5mL) would be "Ba" or "Do", etc.

My question is: **do you have any good suggestions to such a metric counting system?** What syllables should I use to count? *I can also use something else, as long as it is different from the imperial number count* so that I can switch between them according to my needs. I guess the most important thing is that it is easy (low chance of screwing up the counting) and that each syllable roughly can correspond to a 5mL pour. That way I can do pretty much any pour required in a cocktail-recipe (after some practice).

Comment: Why not try Ba-Car-Di-Ba-Car-Di for 6 syllables? Longer term it won't matter - you will just learn the time. It comes automatically with practice

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I started to use this count:

| Count: | Do | Re | Mi | Fa | So | La | Ti | Do |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Volume [mL]: | 5 | 10 | 15 | 20 | 25 | 30 | 35 | 40 |

Here are my reasons for chosing this count system:

1. *The syllables take roughly the same time to pronounce.* This ensures a nice consistency in the count (the same amount of liquid flows from the bottle at each count because they take the same time to "pronounce"). A number counting system does not have this feature as "seven" and "thirteen" would take longer to pronounce than "one" (not a big difference, but still a *bigger* difference)
2. *The five mL increments are useful.* This allows me to easily measure say 15mL or 45mL, which would be harder in another system.
3. *It is easy for me to count 40mL.* This is a common measure in drinks at bars, resturants, etc. where I live (due to alcohol regulations I think). I know that if I finish the whole count, I have 40mL. Easy to remember.
4. *It is easy to remember.* It is very easy (at least for me) to remember the count due to its relation to music. This allows me to focus more on training my timing so that I pour the correct amount. I also need to learn to quickly convert from count to mL (i.e. Do-Re-Mi = 15mL), but this needs to be done regardless of counting system. An easy to remember count lets me focus more on these things.
5. *The counts (most of the time) does not repeat.* My other suggested count ba-ba-ba-ba-car-di had a lot of repeated ba's which made it hard to differentiate between 10mL or 15mL. The only problem here is over 40mL, where there are two do's in a row (re-starting the count). However, this is not really a problem as I also "sing it with tones" such that the first do has a low tone and the last one has a high tone. This way they are sort of "different" and I don't have a problem confusing them.
6. *I can take my sweet time pronouncing the count (due to its shortness).* The shortness of each syllable ensures that I have more than enough time to pronounce them before the next syllable. If I were to use a something longer like "seven" I'd need to pronounce it quicker to ensure that I don't overpour. An extreme example: imagine counting "baseballplayer" for 5mL. You may have poured 10mL by the time you have pronounced "baseballplayer".
7. *It calms me and slows down my time perception.* This is related to the previous point. Since the syllables are so short, i often end up with something like "dooooo-reeeee-miiiii-faaaaa" (slow pronounciation). Saying it slowly is calming and gives an illution that the pouring is "slow", giving me more control during the pour.
8. *Since it doesn't use numbers it still allows me to use the imperial count as well.* I mentioned this in my question, but this is indeed practical. The recipe specifies 1oz? No problem: I can use the imperial count system. The recipe specifies 40mL? No problem: I can use this count system. Now it doesn't matter if the recipe uses oz or mL (or cL). I can measure them both.
9. (Bonus): *Even when I use the count many times, it doesn't quickly become annoying or tiring.* I feel some counts could become annoying very qucikly, but this one works fine for me. I guess it is because I use different tones to pronounce the syllables that it doesn't get monotomous, boring or annoying quickly.

Comment: Wouldn't "A, B, C, …, V" be just as easy for the same reasons, and also allow up to 22 counts?

Comment: Kind of. Some letters are "longer" (not significantly though) to pronounce (ex: H is longer tha E)  than others, but it mostly would work. So yes, you could chose this count instead.

Comment: As for the 22 counts: if you use 5mL increments you can pour 110mL, but you usually don't need anything over 70mL (So the count is unnececary long). It is not practical to reduce the increments to say 2.5mL eigther. As 1) you very rearly need increments lower than 5mL and 2) increments under 5mL could be very unprecice when free-pouring. But still: the idea is not bad.